# Group Policy: Block Word and Excel Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, macros, group-policy

I've activated a GPO for blocking Word and Excel Macros for all our users.
We have some internal created Excel files that require macros, but they are not used in a specific location, so at the moment I'm not supposed to configure trusted folders.

Excel and Word Trust Center Settings:

```
Block macros from running in Office files from the Internet -> activated
VBA Macro Notification Settings -> Disable all without notification
```

What happens is that every document with macros will be blocked without notification like downloaded documents and documents attatched to E-Mails.
And our self created Excel files with macros still work and show a warning and the possibility to activate macros, which is fine.
But I want users to get the notification "Blocked by admin" which is not happening in this scenario.

To get it working I can set:

```
VBA Macro Notification Settings -> Disable all with notification
```

Then users would get the blocked notification without being able to activate the macros. Unfortunately then documents with macros attatched to e-mails will not be blocked anymore, it will only work for downloaded documents.
Attatched documents will only show a warning with the button for activating, which is what I want to avoid.

Do you know a way to disable both downloaded and mail attatched macro documents with a working notification? Is there a reason attachted files are not recognized as files from the internet?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Push, push, push?